# How to cache Django rest framework generics.ListAPIView response

Tags: python-3.x, django, caching, django-rest-framework, django-views

models.py

```
class PaymentMode(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    icon = models.CharField(max_length=350, default='', null=True)
```

serializer.py

```
class PaymentModeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = PaymentMode
        fields ='__all__'
```

Views.py

```
class PaymentModesList(generics.ListAPIView):
    queryset = PaymentMode.objects.all()
    serializer_class = PaymentModeSerializer
```

[URL to DRFcaching documentation](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/caching/)

can someone please help me with how I can cache this response and not do a query as I think this response will be the same for all user for a vast majority of the time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By looking at the docs you provided it seems that the only thing you need is to override the method used by the `generics.ListAPIView`, which is the [get() method](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#listapiview). Check the code below.

You can also change the cache timeout that is passed, to better understand it's behaviour check [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/cache/#the-per-view-cache).

```
from django.utils.decorators import method_decorator
from django.views.decorators.cache import cache_page

class PaymentModesList(generics.ListAPIView):
    queryset = PaymentMode.objects.all()
    serializer_class = PaymentModeSerializer

    # Cache page for the requested url
    @method_decorator(cache_page(60*60*2))
    def get(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return super().get(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Thanks for this.This solution seems to work will have to test on performance and I'm figuring out a way to do it. any suggestions

Comment: @Akashgkrishnan Great! Good to hear that it helped! Don't forget to mark as answer if it solved your issue ;D

Comment: @Akashgkrishnan I'm not used to test cache solutions, however I think [this link](https://testdriven.io/blog/django-caching/) may help you.